# VBA MailMerge from Excel - Error Message waiting for OLE action

Tags: excel, vba, mailmerge

Good Morning

I'm trying to clean up a macro that is behaving erraticly. It used to work - on a good day. But it throws up this error: "Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action". I've tried to clean it up (which caused all sorts of other errors, now sorted) and I'm back to being able to step through it but it again stops at above error.

What I have noticed that it used to do one certificate and then throw the error but now the error occurs straight away when it's trying to open the template. This is the line:
Set objMMMD = objWord.Documents.Open(cDir & WTempName)
objMMMD.Activate

My original thought was that the code didn't close Word cleanly but now that the error is so early, that can't be it. I don't have Word open. - Since it used to open Word before my revision, the code should be correct as well.

I can't find much on the error apart from that it seems to occur in more complicate codes due to timeout and how to suppress the message. Neither seems to be of help here.

Below the entire code. Does anybody have any idea why Excel can't open Word to do the mailmerge?

```
Public Sub MailMergeCert()

Dim bCreatedWordInstance As Boolean
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim objMMMD As Word.Document

Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim Training As String
Dim SeminarDate As String
Dim HoursComp As String
Dim Location As String
Dim Objectives As String
Dim Trainer As String

Dim cDir As String
Dim ThisFileName As String

'Your Sheet names need to be correct in here
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ultrasound")

Dim r As Long
r = 2

FirstName = sh1.Cells(r, 1).Value
LastName = sh1.Cells(r, 2).Value
Training = sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value
SeminarDate = Format(sh1.Cells(r, 4).Value, "d mmmm YYYY")
HoursComp = sh1.Cells(r, 5).Value
Location = sh1.Cells(r, 6).Value
Objectives = sh1.Cells(r, 7).Value
Trainer = sh1.Cells(r, 8).Value

'Setup filenames
Const WTempName = "Certificate_Ultrasound_2017.docx" 'Template name

'Data Source Location
cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\" 'Change if required
ThisFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name

On Error Resume Next

'Create Word instance
bCreatedWordInstance = False
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

If objWord Is Nothing Then
  Err.Clear
  Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  bCreatedWordInstance = True
  End If

If objWord Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Could not start Word"
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
End If

' Let Word trap the errors
On Error GoTo 0

' Set to True if you want to see the Word Doc flash past during construction
objWord.Visible = False

'Open Word Template
Set objMMMD = objWord.Documents.Open(cDir & WTempName)
objMMMD.Activate

'Merge the data
With objMMMD
    .MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=cDir & ThisFileName, _
        sqlstatement:="SELECT *  FROM `Ultrasound$`"   ' Set this as required

lastrow = Sheets("Ultrasound").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


        For r = 2 To lastrow
        If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 11).Value) = False Then GoTo nextrow

            With objMMMD.MailMerge  'With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
            .SuppressBlankLines = True

            With .DataSource
                 .FirstRecord = r - 1
                .LastRecord = r - 1
                .ActiveRecord = r - 1
            End With
            .Execute Pause:=False
            End With

'Save new file PDF
Dim UltrasoundCertPath As String
UltrasoundCertPath = "C:\Users\305015724\Documents\ApplicationsTraining\2016\Ultrasound\"
Dim YYMM As String
YYMM = Format(sh1.Cells(r, 16).Value, "YYMM")
Dim NewFileNamePDF As String
NewFileNamePDF = YYMM & "_" & sh1.Cells(r, 3).Value & "_" & sh1.Cells(r, 7).Value '& ".pdf" 'Change File Name as req'd"
objWord.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat UltrasoundCertPath & NewFileNamePDF, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF

nextrow:
        Next r

End With


' Close the Mail Merge Main Document
objMMMD.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
Set objMMMD = Nothing
If bCreatedWordInstance Then
objWord.Quit
End If

Set objWord = Nothing
Cells(r, 11).Value = Date

0:
Set objWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look in Task Manager and see how many copies of Word are running. (Check in "processes", not just in "applications".)  Each time you run the code you are creating a new Word application (`Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")`) and, if that doesn't work, you try again and set a flag (`bCreatedWordInstance`).  But you only `Quit` the application if the flag is set, i.e. only if the first attempt at creating the new application failed but the second attempt worked.

Comment: @YowE3K - I do close down Word through processes so none are open. - I have to admit I copied most of the code and don't really understand what  the bCreatedWordInstance does. I also struggle with the 2 IF bits. It seems to me that I open Word and then check if Word is open? But maybe that's good error handling. - However, my error occurs only a few lines later. I have opened Word (otherwise I would get the MsgBox) and I'm now trying to open the template. Nothing happens and Excel waits in vain. - So the quitting Word can't have an impact yet? Christine

Comment: I'm looking at my code. Where it opens Word, does "bCreatedWordInstance = False" mean, that it's checking whether Word is open already? How does it know what bCreatedWordInstance is? It's declared but I can't see code (and I have checked the original code this was copied from) to determine that.

Comment: It's now throwing a runtime error 462 remote server machine does not exist. I have put ' in front of code and taken it away again so it's all the same again. I don't understand how code can be erratic. Shoudn't it be black or white?

Comment: Normally people would try to see whether an instance of Word was already open (using `GetObject` I think).  If that didn't work, they would try using `CreateObject` and set a flag (you're using a variable you have called `bCreatedWordInstance`) to show that the code created the instance and therefore it should be closed when the code is finished with it.  If the flag isn't set (because it never goes through the bit using `CreateObject`) then the code leaves the instance open because it was open when the code started.  But you are using `CreateObject` twice, which doesn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path + "\"
```

To

```
cDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

Does that make a difference. Also try printing the cDir if its what expect.

Try message box the cDir to check the path.

```
MsgBox(cDir, vbOKOnly, "Testing cDir")
```

Comment: No difference. How do I print cDir? Thanks, Christine

Comment: Just use a message box.